# can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? ast.literal_eval malformed node or string python3

Tags: python

Hei,

I'm trying to convert the dict from a string to a dict using ast.literal_eval but I, for some reason get an error. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can anyone tell me why it wont work?

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("""{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "id": 1,
   "result": {
      "moreAvailable": false,
      "currentOrders": [
         {
            "sizeCancelled": 0.0,
            "marketId": "1.117685350",
            "priceSize": {
               "price": 1.03,
               "size": 30.0
            },
            "placedDate": "2015-03-11T14:55:51.000Z",
            "sizeLapsed": 0.0,
            "orderType": "LIMIT",
            "averagePriceMatched": 1.03,
            "bspLiability": 0.0,
            "matchedDate": "2015-03-11T14:55:57.000Z",
            "sizeRemaining": 0.0,
            "selectionId": 1485567,
            "side": "BACK",
            "betId": "47371597910",
            "persistenceType": "LAPSE",
            "handicap": 0.0,
            "status": "EXECUTION_COMPLETE",
            "regulatorCode": "DANISH GAMBLING AUTHORITY",
            "sizeVoided": 0.0,
            "sizeMatched": 30.0
         }
      ]
   }
}""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 33, in <module>
    }""")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 62, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 61, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 62, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 61, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000000052FE278>
```

Comment: I disagree that this is a "simple typographical error".  OP didn't accidentally mistype `json.loads` as `ast.literal_eval`... :-)

Comment: @mgilson your right, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. i've done a json request and got the response as a string, and need to convert it to a dict. the string is what's in the ast.literal_eval tag. If i do manual change the "false" to "False" it works. but can i make my json.dump/load or ast command do that for me?

Comment: Just use `json.loads` rather than `ast.literal_eval` and you should be all set.  My comment was directed at whomever voted to close this question saying that it was a typographical error (and to document my opinion so others can see it an consider it before they choose to cast a close vote).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`false` is not a valid literal in Python (it's `False`<sup>1</sup>).

It looks like you're trying to parse JSON -- in which case [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) might be exactly what you're looking for.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Actually, on python2.x, `False` isn't a literal at all, it's a *Name* (`ast.dump(ast.parse('False'))`).  It is [special cased](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/36bd5add9732/Lib/ast.py#l64) by `ast.literal_eval` (along with `True` and `None`) to evaluate to the proper value ...</sup>

Comment: Man! Eagle's eye. *egil*son

Comment: @BhargavRao -- The key was that the `ValueError` was raised on an `_ast.Name` object.  That clued me in that I should be looking for something that python would usually interpret as a name (ruling out strings or syntax errors).  From there, finding the `false` wasn't too tricky to spot.

Comment: your right :) it's at json return, my return looks like this:
    json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)
can i do something to make it work? :)
and thanks for the fast reply :)